# How to use double quotes in variable to execute it in backquote?

Tags: bash

I want to put result of find command to variable - and I have a problem with variable inside command substitution block. Bellow short example:

```
#!/bin/bash

pattern='"file*"'
res=$(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name ${pattern}) # doesn't work
#res=$(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "file*") # works
echo $res
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
pattern="file*"
res=$( find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "${pattern}" )
```

Comment: This is equal to 
"find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name file*"

It will not work when there are several files with such name mask. For example "file1" and "file2".